# nodejs javascript promise resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, async-await, es6-promise

I can't seem to figure out how to save the results of `SomeQuery` promise. Essentially I would like to take the value in `res` and pipe it into `parseQuery` function and return the final results. How do I make the parsed result accessible to an APIs response.

```js
const neo4j = require('neo4j-driver')
var parser = require('parse-neo4j')
const astria_queries = require('./astriaQueries')

const uri = 'bolt://astria_graph:7687'
const user = 'xxx'
const password = 'xxx'

const someQuery = (query) => {
  //   run statement in a transaction
  const driver = neo4j.driver(uri, neo4j.auth.basic(user, password))
  const session = driver.session({ defaultAccessMode: neo4j.session.READ })
  const tx = session.beginTransaction()

  tx.run(query)
    .then((res) => {
      // Everything is OK, the transaction will be committed
      parseQuery(res)
    })
    .then(() => {
      // Everything is OK, the transaction will be committed
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      // The transaction will be rolled back, now handle the error.
      console.log(e)
    })
    .finally(() => {
      session.close()
      driver.close()
    })
}

const parseQuery = (result) => {
  try {
    const test = parser.parse(result)
    console.log(test)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}

module.exports = {
  someQuery,
}
```

Comment: Did you try https://www.npmjs.com/package/neo4j-driver#explicit-transactions approach? Creating one transaction and than await each run?

Comment: Is there some code missing in `parseQuery`? If not, why do you create a new `results` array if it ends up with the same content as `parsed`?
Unless I'm missing something, the code could just become:
`const parseQuery = (result) => result.then(parser.parse).catch((err) => console.log(err))`

Comment: @fbiville the results array was not needed. So I removed it. I am trying your recommendations and have *updated* the code above. It is still not working as expected. Thanks for your time.

Comment: indeed, because `res` (in `someQuery` snippet) is not a promise, my bad.
I guess the code should actually be like: `const parseQuery = (result) => { try { return parser.parse(result.records) } catch (err) { console.error(err) } }` 
`
It's hard to know for sure without seeing the `parse` implementation of the `parser`.

Comment: @fbiville thanks, that got me closer. The final step is how can I save the results from the parseQuery function so I can send it as a response to an API. Is there a way to exports.modules = someQuery().then(resolve(parseQuery)?

Answer (score 1):

It finally clicked with me. Here is the solution I came up with. Hopefully it will help others. If there is a better way please let me know. Thank you @fbiville for you help.

*async actions*

```js
const neo4j = require('neo4j-driver')
var parser = require('parse-neo4j')
const astria_queries = require('./astriaQueries')

const uri = 'bolt://astria_graph:7687'
const user = 'neo4j'
const password = 'neo'

async function getRecords(query) {
  //   run statement in a transaction
  const driver = neo4j.driver(uri, neo4j.auth.basic(user, password))
  const session = driver.session({ defaultAccessMode: neo4j.session.READ })
  const tx = session.beginTransaction()
  try {
    const records = await tx.run(query)
    const parseRecords = await parseQuery(records)
    return parseRecords
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  } finally {
    session.close()
    driver.close()
  }
}

async function parseQuery(result) {
  try {
    const parsedRes = await parser.parse(result)
    // console.log(parsedRes)
    return parsedRes
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}

// getRecords(astria_queries.get_data_sources)

module.exports = {
  getRecords,
}
```

*api send()*

```js
exports.get_data_sources = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    queryFuns.getRecords(astria_queries.get_data_sources).then((response) => {
      res.send(response)
    })
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error)
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```